# cometd client connection to multiple servers

Tags: java, dojo, cometd

We are developing an application using dojo 1.7.2 and cometd 2.5. We want to have the client connect to two servers (not at the same time). The client has to connect to a first server to do some business logic, and based on the success of the logic it must then connect to a second server.

For now I can connect to one server but I have no clue about how to make the connection to the second server. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect with CometD to multiple servers, you need to instantiate multiple JavaScript CometD objects.

Normally you get one instantiated by default, in form of `dojox.cometd` or passed as parameter to a `require()` function.

To create multiple objects, [follow the documentation](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#javascript_configure_multiple_objects).